# Terraform plan, not producing outputs/crashing reporting, provider connection shutdown or unexpected EOF

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have spent 2 days now trying to figure out why terraform plan would not produce any outputs, you run the command and it just stops. After tinkering for a while i started getting some outputs.

module.provider.aws Connection shutdown
provider.aws Unexpected EOF

This lead me down the rabbit hole of building different OS boxes and trying different Terraform version with nothing working and the errors just persisting.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

I descided to post it here since there are not many or any answers to this that really helps.
After resetting everything and going back to basics i.e. google some stuff, i found on page 4 of google results a magical link stating that terraform requires a minimum of 5.2GB of RAM to perform optimally.

THIS IS NOWHERE IN THE TERRAFORM DOCS. i waisted almost 2 days trying to figure this out and the issue could have been solved with terraform introduction documentation just saying min requirements for this shit.

anyway enough ranting, here is the magic link.
https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022608473-Runs-sometimes-failing-with-connection-is-shut-down-or-unexpected-EOF-

In short always make sure you run terraform on a machine with atleast 6GB of RAM and you will be good.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't true at all for the Terraform command line client. I regularly run Terraform in CI in containers limited to much less memory than that and are running on instances with less total memory as well. Are you hitting this issue with running Terraform Enterprise? If so you should edit the question and answer combo to make that clearer. Also, even a self answered question should include enough information that it's possible to answer. Right now I'd vote to close your question to not including any information to debug it at all.

Comment: Whereas in my case I did not need 6GB, I did have to increase the RAM. The version that I use is quite old (0.11.X) though. There is an issue too in github: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13919